# Is it good to design a web page, using tags other than DIV?

Tags: html, xhtml, css

Is it good to design a web page, using tags other than DIV's?

And, in case there are such tags worth its use, please let me know their advantage or disadvantage.

Comment: Just use what you need. You have to know when to use each element. Be sure to look into the new html5 elements such as header, nav, article, section. Use your div only for the layout.

Comment: More div tags than what?

Answer (score 6):

div tags are container tags.  Putting content into a container tag allows you to do the following:

1. Use margins or padding to tweak the position of the contained content
2. Put a border around the contained content
3. Position the contained content with float, absolute or relative positioning
4. Hide/show a group of content all at once by hiding/showing the div
5. Assign a class or id to the div and apply CSS rules to everything in the contained content
6. Apply a common background to the contained content

You need only as many divs as are required to achieve your layout or achieve any future flexibility in styling that you want.  More divs beyond that doesn't do anything for you.

Comment: You forgot to talk about tables: div are a usually a great replacement of tables, because you can do a lot more on divs that you can't on tr's and td's.

Comment: Tables are for tabular data, the only good replacement for tables is when TABLE-based markup has been used for structural purposes.

Answer (score 4):

`<div>` tags are really only for miscellaneous blocks. For better functionality, use the HTML5 tags `<article>`, `<section>`, `<header>`, `<footer>`, `<aside>`, and `<nav>` where appropriate. See [the HTML specs (draft)](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/spec.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Tables are great to display specific data, for example results from experiment. Divs should be used to build whole layout of your website.

Comment: Tables are great for tabular data.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a question to have more or less `div` tags. You have to use the amount of `div` you **really** need. It's true that nowadays `div` tags are more used than `table` also because they makes your code cleaner but again isn't a quantity problem.

Answer (score 0):

DIVs yes, as Aurelio said, it really depends on your design/build on how many you use. Don't do things like put text inside a DIV e.g. `<div class="title">text here</div>`. Put them into `<h1 class="title">text here</h1>`, or, `<p class="txt">txt here</p>` etc

Don't build your website using tables for its structure, or use inline styles on your DIVs e.g. `<div style="color:#ccc; font-size: 12px;">text here</p>`.